# Unable to create stripe token

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am trying to create token of Card but I don't know how to do it.
let say I have Data like this in my state

```
this.state = {
paymentInfo : {
cardNumber : '4242424242424242',
expiry_month : 12,
expiry_year : 22,
cardCvc : 123
} 
}

createToken = () => {
  const {stripe} = this.props;
  const element = stripe.elements();

//From here I don't know how to use data in my State to generate a token 
}
```

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems to be a matter of posting the information to the propper endpoint https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/create_card also checkout https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: check this [stripe card](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#set-up-stripe-elements)

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach is to *not* maintain credit card information in your React state. If you handle credit card information in this way, it opens up your business to complex regulatory requirements [1]. Avoiding this is one of the main benefits of using Stripe, and specifically, Stripe Elements [2].

For React, the following docs here will guide you through the process of accepting a payment using our latest APIs:

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#web

Each client-side code example in the above guide has a "React" tab that you can switch over to if necessary.

I would also recommend watching Stripe's Developer Office Hours video for getting started with React:

- Video: https://youtu.be/w1oLdAPyuok
- Demo: https://github.com/tmarek-stripe/demo-react-stripe-js

If you absolutely must handle credit card information in this way, then of course, Stripe can accommodate that. The approach would be to securely send the credit card information to your server, and tokenize the details using the following API here:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/create

Note that the PaymentMethods API is Stripe's new API for tokenizing card details (replacing the Tokens API).

[1] https://stripe.com/en-dk/guides/pci-compliance
[2] https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js

Comment: Found this Article https://w3path.com/react-stripe-payment-gateway-with-custom-form/