# How to use Custom Fields data Instead of react-stripe-elements

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, payment

I am trying to Use my **Custom Fields** Data which I have taken from the User such as ,**Card Number** and **expiry year**, **expiry Month** and **CVC** .I have googled every where but everyone seems to be using **react-stripe-elements** for the **payment** process but i want to use my **Custom Fields** ,I have tried many way's to achieve that but since i am new to react I can't seem solve it on my own so if anyone Knows about it .your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to create stripe token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61755834/unable-to-create-stripe-token)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you asked more or less [this same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61755834/unable-to-create-stripe-token/61758704#61758704) yesterday, and it was answered in detail.

While it is not the recommended approach unless you have a deep need, you can send card details to the API to [create a payment method](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/create#create_payment_method-card-number), but this carries an additional [PCI compliance](https://stripe.com/docs/security#validating-pci-compliance) burden for you (click "API Direct" on that page).